# Something wrong with sorting

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have a data frame (df) like this

```
Name   Value
P       9.1
M       14.3
P       12.4
C       10.5
```

I tried sorting it using

```
df[order(df$value),]
```

and get something like this

```
Name      Value
C          10.5
P          12.4 
M          14.3 
P           9.1
```

Can you tell me what is going on?

Comment: `df$Value` is probably not numeric. `df[order(as.numeric(df$Value)),]` should be a quick fix. But you should probably change the column type with `df$value <- as.numeric(df$Value)`.

Comment: What does `class(df$value)` say?

Comment: check `df$value` - it's probably character.

Comment: Is ```value``` supposed to be ```Value``` in ```order```?

Comment: Also, check `str(df)` to see if there are problems with any of your other columns.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's a factor. If it were a character column it would get printed with quotation marks, so this is the fix to the ordering:

```
df[ order(as.numeric(as.character(df$value))), ]
```

Comment: So here df$value is first converted into character from factor and then into numeric. Then it is sorted using order. Am I correct?

Comment: That's it, exactly. You read the order of function calls from the "inside out".

Comment: I was wondering why I need to convert factor into character first and then into numeric? Why can't I go from factor to numeric straight?

Comment: Because factors are already numeric, except they are _numeric_ pointers to a character vector. So if you just do "as.numeric" you get "10.2" < "2.0" as TRUE. You have apparently inadvertently constructed a vector that has character representations of numbers. This is typical fo data converted from Excel, but might have occurred for other reasons. AND .... Why are you arguing with me, anyway? And why haven't you answered teh sensible requests in the comments? Just do it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I wasn't arguing. Just wanted to know the reasons for doing what I am doing as I am new to r.